# mysql - getting the correct column values with max()

Tags: mysql, max

I have two tables, `item` and `prices`.

The `prices` table holds the price of each item in the `item` table. There is one extra field named `counter` in the prices table - which is stored and incremented by one in periodic manner. So, for each counter there will be a set of **N** rows in the prices table, where N is the number of items in the item table.

```
CREATE TABLE `item` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `prices` (
  `id` bigint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  `price` float(10,2) NOT NULL,  
  `ts` datetime NOT NULL,
  `counter` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `item_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `ts` (`ts`),
  KEY `counter` (`item_id`,`counter`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Now, I need to find out the maximum value of price corresponding to each item - on any particular day - along with the counter value.

There could be multiple rows with the same price for any item - need to select the first occurrence.

I have tried the following query.

```
SELECT p.id, p.counter, max.price
FROM prices AS p
JOIN (

SELECT item_id, MAX( price ) as price
FROM prices
WHERE ts
BETWEEN  '2017-07-28 00:00:00'
AND  '2017-07-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY item_id
)
max 

ON max.item_id = p.item_id
and p.price= max.price
```

This doesn't give the desired result.

How do I correct my query?

Thanks.

### Edit - Sample data

```
select id, item_id, price,counter from prices order by item_id, price;
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
| id    | item_id | price | counter |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
| 30192 |      54 | 18.95 |     200 |
| 15061 |      54 | 19.15 |     100 |
|  7503 |      54 | 19.45 |      50 |
| 22598 |      54 | 19.75 |     150 |
| 30127 |     100 | 30.20 |     200 |
| 22569 |     100 | 30.35 |     150 |
| 15033 |     100 | 30.35 |     100 |
|  7460 |     100 | 30.90 |      50 |
| 15084 |     115 | 25.35 |     100 |
|  7533 |     115 | 25.65 |      50 |
| 22623 |     115 | 25.75 |     150 |
| 30152 |     115 | 26.20 |     200 |
+-------+---------+-------+---------+
```

Need to get the following output.

```
id,     item_id,     price,     counter
22598   1           19.75       150
7460    2           30.90       50  
30152   3           26.20       200
```

ps: neglected timestamp for the time being.

Comment: `This doesn't give the desired result.` ... what is your current output and how is it wrong?

Comment: Incidentally, it's highly unlikely that a price would be float. It's why decimal was invented

Comment: please find the sample data and expected output added.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't do a join, just try a subselect, ie:

```
SELECT p.id, p.counter, p.max_price FROM
(SELECT item_id, MAX( price ) as max_price
FROM prices
WHERE ts
BETWEEN  '2017-07-28 00:00:00'
AND  '2017-07-28 23:59:59'
GROUP BY item_id) AS p;
```

Comment: I don't think this would give a different result than what the OP already has.

Comment: Oh I see, I think the issue is with the `group by item_id` which will disregard the MAX(price) and just take the first value it finds suitable

Comment: Maybe...let's wait for the OP to show us some data.